# Eclipse 3.6.2. refuses to debug applications built with Eclipse 3.6.1

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

Actually, the problem is bi-directional: Eclipse 3.6.2. refuses to update the install of applications built with Eclipse 3.6.1 (when selecting Run or Debug) - and vice versa: 3.6.1 won't update install of applications built (and installed) with 3.6.2.

The error message indicates that "they are signed differently", despite the fact that they are built from the **same exact source tree**.

Is this a known issue?

Since I have to daily switch back and forth between one workstation to another, this is an annoyance. I could of course make sure that both run 3.6.2, but I wonder if this behavior is due to something I did wrong (configuration/setting) and whether there is a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is expected behavior, possibly its even so when you have two workstations with Eclipse 3.6.2 the application still gets signed differently, because they might use a different debug keystore. A possible solution might be to copy the keystore used for debugging, which should be in your user directory somewhere. The path to it is in the preferences menu -> android -> build -> Default debug keystore.

You might need to use a custom one even, but i've not tried so I wouldn't know.

Comment: Yes, just copy the debug keystore from workstation A to workstation B, and remove/uninstall all .apk's that were previously built with workstation B.

Comment: @MrJre Ouch! You are right: The keystore is not part of the project and not even part of the Eclipse install but rather taken from each user's home directory by default. Thanks!